# Show SnackBar from a custom Scaffold base

Tags: dart, flutter

I am having difficulties trying to achieve a unified `Scaffold` theme. My initial thought was to cleanup my UI and reuse the code of the shareable elements of my scaffolding across the application. So now I have a base `Scaffold` with the default configuration that is used by any screen that builds `MyScaffold`. However, when I started to implement error handling I started to face this problem of accessing the context or the state of `MyScaffold`. So if I have a screen that makes use of the base `Scaffold` and it needs to show a SnackBar at some point, it would be something like:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyScaffold(
      //custom configuration
    );


  }
  //Called somehwere
    void signIn() async{
      try{
        // await signIn
      }
      catch(e){
        // showSnackBar
      }
    }
}
```

However, I am unable to show the `SnackBar` because the conext and the state of `LoginScreen` does not contain a real `Scaffold` but `MyScaffold` is the correct widget to handle showing a `SnackBar`. Is this achievable or should I drop my base `Scaffold` and re-write the common configuration parts. One example for what I mean by configurations is that I style my `Scaffold` differently based on the `Platform`.

One thing I have tried is using a `GlobalKey`

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _authScaffold =GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

 return MyScaffold(
      key:_authScaffold ,...
```

and on the same widget I call

```
 _authScaffold.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text(message)));
```

but I get

```
 NoSuchMethodError: The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 1337): Receiver: null
```

Comment: Is there a `Scaffold` inside `MyScaffold`? If yes, you can with a GlobalKey or using a different `context`. If no, you'll have to reimplement snackbar layout there

Comment: Yes it does have a `Scaffold`, I have tried to pass down a `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` and call `currentState` on that but it is working as if the key is not initialized (called on null)

Comment: I have update the post with my attempt of using `GlobalKey`

Comment: You should move that logic into the child of `MyScaffold` so that you can use `Scaffold.of(context)`

Comment: Yes this works, thank you Rémi.

Answer (score 1):

As Rémi answered in the comments, moving the widgets under your MyScaffold is the best way of doing it, as that way the BuildContext you're using is a context that includes the scaffold.

If needed, you can use a `Builder` widget to get a context lower down in the tree without having to make a new widget class.

But to address the reason why `GlobalKey` wan't working for you - I have to guess a little as you didn't include code for your MyScaffold, but since you were passing `key` to your MyScaffold, I assume you weren't passing it down further as both Stateful and Stateless widgets have a `key` parameter. What you should have been doing is passing a different value i.e. `scaffoldKey`, and then within your MyWidget's build function passing the scaffoldKey to `Scaffold(key: scaffoldKey)`. But using globalkeys is generally avoidable and not recommended.